# How can I pass environment variables to a Docker container with Terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform

I'm spawning Docker containers using Terraform's Docker provider, but fail to understand how to pass them environment variables.

The project's documentation on the `env` option states :

> env - (Optional, set of strings) Environment variables to set.

What is a "set of strings" in context ? Can you provide an example docker container resource declaration that uses the `env` option ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Terraforming a Docker environment](http://t0t0.github.io/internship%20week%209/2016/05/02/terraform-docker.html):

```
# Start elastic container
resource "docker_container" "elastic" {
    image = "${docker_image.elastic.latest}"
    name = "elastic"
    hostname = "elastic"
    env = ["SERVICE=elastic", "PROJECT=stage", "ENVIRONMENT=operations"]
    restart= "no"
    must_run="true"
}
```

Comment: So the Terraform documentation should really have the word 'set' changed to 'array'.

Comment: Or rather "list', because that's how that data structure is called in the part of the docs that covers variable types

Comment: will it reveal the actual value if I pass the tf variable here? e.g. "HOST=aws_db_instance.burp_db.address"